# Checking if variable is empty

Tags: php

First I will paste my code than explain.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $username=$row['username'];
    $email=$row['email'];
    $firstname=$row['firstname'];
    $lastname=$row['lastname'];
    $motto=$row['motto'];
    $bio=$row['bio'];
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM photo where id='$id'");
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4))
{
$image=$row4['filename'];
$src = (empty($image)) ? "upload/your-photo.jpg" : "site_images/$id/$image";
}
```

As you can tell the problem has to do with the image. I'm thinking the problem is where it SELECTS * FROM photo where id='$id' because this is in a while loop and if it is empty like it says in $src than it just moves on to the next person in line.

I was wondering how it would be possible to make this work? Right now it is just displaying the same image for every id when it should show the correct image.

Comment: Maybe some explanation of what is supposed to happen...?

Comment: ..or, you could echo out the actual query from the $result4 and run that directly to see if you are getting a column named 'filename' and that there are results..

Comment: I said it in the last sentence of my post. $image is supposed to output the correct data inside the row filename where the id = $id and the only problem is that I declared $id inside a while statement which I have to so I believe it is just skipping the validation I have in the variable $src.

Comment: @ChrisLively as I said already in my post it is outputting the row filename for each $id as the same filename. Look at this image for better clarification. http://gyazo.com/400d4ea365e4b552464af2c0c597d669

Comment: Is there more code you aren't showing?  Because you are overwriting the $src variable for every id you find in the second `while()` loop.  I don't see where it (or really any of those vars) are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try breaking out the conditional where you have the inner loop:

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM photo where id='$id'");
while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4))
{
  $image=$row4['filename'];
  $src = "upload/your-photo.jpg";
  if(!empty($image)) {
     $src = "site_images/$id/$image";
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try using:

```
strlen
```

and checking if it's equal to 0

Also, in your database, does your photo table have rows with with IDs but no photo file specified?  Perhaps you are querying an empty table..

Answer (score 3):

You should just have one query with a join in it, to join the photo table.